Xamarin Forms APK Update
I've got an app called MyApp.apk. I can download an update but it fails to install saying "There was a problem parsing the package.", however, when I try to update the app using another app, with the same exact code and apk download link it successfully updates.
So MySecondaryApp.apk can update MyApp.apk, but, MyApp.apk cannot update its self.
APK signing is not the issue.
Package name is not the issue.
Any ideas?

Connect your phone via USB/ADB to your PC with ADB/Android SDK installed and install the APK using the command adb install MyApp.apk then you will get an error message that explains why installation fails.
